# WPF BarChart Data

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am about to learn WPF Charts and found a good tutorial here: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/BarChartWPF11192009112620AM/BarChartWPF.aspx

So i followed all the steps till "Figure 7". My problem is, that in my application, no chart bar is visible. 
I can see the BackgroundColor and the legend, but there is no chart. 
Here is my Code:

```
            <TabItem Header="Charts" Name="tabCharts" >
                <charts:Chart Name="firstChart" Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Width="400" Height="250" Background="LightSteelBlue">
                    <charts:Chart.Series>
                        <charts:BarSeries Title="Finanzübersicht" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">

                        </charts:BarSeries>
                    </charts:Chart.Series>
                </charts:Chart>
            </TabItem>
```

and in my code-behind file:

```
    private void LoadBarChartData()
    {
       ((BarSeries)firstChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
             new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 12),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("CEO", 25),

      };
```

Does anybody know what is the reason why I can´t see no data/no bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check namespace and names

```
xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

and call LoadBarChartData on ChartTypeBar constructor

```
public ChartTypeBar()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadBarChartData();  
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I changed that but there is still no data. Do you know another reason why it eventually doesn´t work?

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution! Great!

Comment: Do you even know why I have to put it into a own class?